# Run script after network is connected

Tags: linux, networking, initialization

Placing files in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` you can invoke a script whenever the interface is brought up. But that doesn't mean internet connectivity has been established. This happens to me quite frequently. For instance, the code below

```
#!/bin/sh

# Don't bother to do anything for lo.
if [ "$IFACE" = lo ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# Only run from ifup.
if [ "$MODE" != start ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# we only care about inet and inet6.
case $ADDRFAM in
    inet|inet6|NetworkManager)
        ;;  
    *)  
        exit 0
        ;;  
esac


/path/to/my/script

exit 0
```

Calls the script as soon as interface is brought up. But most often, I still do not have network connectivity, so my script fails because it tries to connect to the web.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the interface is up, it doesn't means that you have a connectivity at all. If the interface is configured to get IP from DHCP for example, few seconds are needed for the IP configurations.

To check for Internet connectivity, you can query the IP of a known webpage with `nslookup` or `dig`. If you get a valid answer you can proceed. Otherwise, wait and repeat for a certain number of retries before aborting.

Now why to use the DNS system to check for Internet connectivity? I think that is the most easy and convenient way to check that all network aspects are properly configured (IP address, routes, DNS, etc).

Comment: Or ping a reliable remote site such as google, (hoping it is not blocked by some big bad firewall).

Comment: So currently that is what I do, but to me, that is a hack. Is there a way to run the script when you get connectivity?

Comment: @rasharasha `ping` is discouraged. Unless you want to check for local network connectivity. In such case you perform broadcast ping at your subnet and you wait for at least one valid response.

Comment: @Kousha I doubt there is a convenient integrated way.